# Rgraph: How to show average on top of stacked bar?

Tags: javascript, rgraph

I am using Rgraph and I want to show average at the top of each stacked bar graph.

How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

First StackOverflow question in ages - take a chocolate!

For this you can use the labelsAbove option - like these examples:

[UPDATE: See below]

These are stacked Bar charts:

[UPDATE: See below]

This one is slightly different in that it adds the labels when the wave animation effect is finished:

[UPDATE: See below]

Or this one shows the labels at the top of the chart:

[UPDATE: See below]

Update: All the demos are available in the download archive:

https://www.rgraph.net/download.html#stable